# High CPU Usage in php-fpm

Tags: wordpress, nginx, php

i am using WordPress Nginx’s fastcgi-cache and have High CPU Usage in php-fpm
i have tracked the process
and all give me the same thing

```
gettimeofday({1399054255, 543565}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1399054255, 543621}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1399054255, 543678}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1399054255, 543739}, NULL) = 0
```

-
and counting all the process doing the same thing
i have searched a lot for the last 5 days and i have tested all what can i do
i have changed themes disabled plugins
i have done new wordpress install but nothing
i have changed php-fpm config files to every thing possible

this is my config now

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 10
pm.start_servers = 4
pm.min_spare_servers = 2
pm.max_spare_servers = 6
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s;
pm.max_requests = 200
```

i do not have visitors
even if i the only visitor the cpu spikes to 100% until the this process ended

```
gettimeofday( NULL) = 0
```

all day long

```
gettimeofday({1399054255, 547438}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1399054255, 547564}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1399054255, 547665}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1399054255, 548304}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1399054255, 548415}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1399054255, 548517}, NULL) = 0
```

please help this is frustrating

update: this command   strace -c -p 21731
give me this

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 99.81    0.080469           0   4888644           gettimeofday
  0.11    0.000088           0      1501           sendto
  0.02    0.000017           0      3500        25 read
  0.02    0.000016           0      2363        26 stat
  0.01    0.000010           0      1926           recvfrom
  0.01    0.000008           0      1801       600 lstat
  0.01    0.000007           0       590           getcwd
  0.00    0.000004           0      1191           clock_gettime
  0.00    0.000000           0       103           write
  0.00    0.000000           0      1074           open
  0.00    0.000000           0      1273           close
  0.00    0.000000           0      1258           fstat
  0.00    0.000000           0      2500           poll
  0.00    0.000000           0      1078           lseek
  0.00    0.000000           0        28           mmap
  0.00    0.000000           0        28           munmap
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           brk
  0.00    0.000000           0        51           rt_sigaction
  0.00    0.000000           0        23           rt_sigprocmask
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           rt_sigreturn
  0.00    0.000000           0         4           ioctl
  0.00    0.000000           0      3090       361 access
  0.00    0.000000           0       128           nanosleep
  0.00    0.000000           0        28           alarm
  0.00    0.000000           0        36           setitimer
  0.00    0.000000           0        30           socket
  0.00    0.000000           0        38        14 connect
  0.00    0.000000           0        11         2 accept
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           recvmsg
  0.00    0.000000           0         9           shutdown
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           bind
  0.00    0.000000           0        21           getsockname
  0.00    0.000000           0        14           getpeername
  0.00    0.000000           0        14           getsockopt
  0.00    0.000000           0        73           fcntl
  0.00    0.000000           0       320           getdents
  0.00    0.000000           0        18           chdir
  0.00    0.000000           0        36           getrusage
  0.00    0.000000           0        18           times
  0.00    0.000000           0       160           openat
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.080619               4912986      1028 total
```

Comment: Do you happen to have xdebug or any other profiling extension like newrelic enabled? I had this same issue and it was newrelic extension causing it. I disabled it and everything seems normal now.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with straight php on the command-line.  I do have xdebug enabled (intentionally), but have always had it enabled and this issue just started appearing recently.  Very odd.